Question about reparameterization homotopy
Lemma. Let $h: I \to I$ bicontinuous and $\sigma : I \to X$. Then $\sigma \simeq \sigma \circ h$ (where $\simeq$ means that are homotopic relative to endpoints).
Proof: Let $h_t: I \to I, h_t(s) = (1-t)h(s) + ts$ and define $\sigma_t := \sigma \circ h_t$. Then $\sigma_t$ is a homotopy between $\sigma$ and $\sigma \circ h$.
I don't understand why $h$ needs to have the inverse continous and can't be only continuous + bijective.

What about $h(t)=0$ for all $t$?

Maybe in the lemma you want a homotopy relative the endpoints? You should add a reference.

Oooh. Ok. But now bicontinuous = continuous, bijective and inverse is continuous. I only need continuous + bijective. Is this true? I also need inverse to be continuous?

@MoisheKohan thanks! I've added now!

OK. What you really need from $h$ is continuity and $h(0)=0, h(1)=1$. Injectivity is not needed.

continuous + bijective implies homeomorphism since $I$ is compact Hausdorff.

@PaulFrost thanks! So in this case we only can have ($h(0) = 0$ and $h(1)=1$) or ($h(0) = 1$ and $h(0) = 0$) because $h$ needs to be strictly monotone. Isn't true?

Yes, it is correct!
